# Definition of $C^k$ boundaries

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I am reading the book "Partial Differential Equations" of Lawrance c. Evans by myself and started with Appendix part.

At the very beginning of Appendix C, there exists a definition
"We say $\partial U$ is $C^k$ if for each point $x^0\in\partial U$, there exists $r>0$ and a $C^k$ function $\gamma:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that we have
$ U\cap B(x^0,r)=\{x\in B(x^0,r)\lvert x_n>\gamma(x_1,...,x_{n-1})\}$
I do not understand the intuition behind this definition.To my understanding it does not correspond to derivatives. Can anyone help me with that? Why we call such boundary sets as $C^k$?

Comment: I think your definition is not quite correct. In your definition the coordinate $x_n$ has a special role, but afaik this should not be the case.

Comment: @supinf the requirement should include a statement like 'after a proper choice of coordinate axes' (but often this is understood and not mentioned explicitly).

Comment: @supinf , you  are right, it also mentions a proper choice of coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition $$x_n > \gamma(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$$ says that, locally, the boundary can be written as the graph of a function -- it means that the boundary itself is locally the set were $$x_n = \gamma(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$$

This is equivalent to saying it is an $n-1$ dimensional submanifold or a hypersurface -- maybe you have heard these words.

The smoothness assumption on $\gamma$ translates to a smoothness statement about this hypersurface. If you would, e.g, only require $\gamma$ to be Lipshitz, this would allow for corners in the boundary. Asking it to be of class $C^k$ with $k\ge 1$ makes it differentiable, or (if e.g. $k\ge 2$ already implies that it curves continuously.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, but wouldn't it be a graph of a function if it were $x_n = \gamma(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$?

Comment: @intmeasure the condtion says that the interior of the set is described by the inequality. So the boundary is described by the equality (which is a graph).

Comment: Oh, I see that now. Thank you very much @Thomas